# How to create temporal heat map in CartoDB?

Tags: carto, animation, torque

I'd like to create an animated heat map, showing the changing temperatures at same locations through time.

It looks like you would create this using a combination of either the choropleth or categorical map and the torque map... but I can't figure out how to link everything together.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest building this using some custom js. Symbolize your data using the intensity type from the wizard in cartodb. Make sure there is a date or another field that can be used to show change over time

Add a simple slider that represents the units for the user to see and that can be used to select a specific subset of your data. The code below shows a slider with min 0 and max 24 to represent hours in a day . You could easily apple this to different time units like days, date etc.

```
            $("#slider").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 24,
            step: 1,
            value: 24,
            change: function (event, ui) {
                var sliderValue = ui.value; 
                var queryText = "SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE (hour <=" + sliderValue + ")"
                yourMapLayer.getSubLayer(0).setSQL(queryText);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a CartoDB answer, bug GeoServer offers a nice feature using its WPS extension in SLD (called Rendering Transformations). See this excellent blog post of Boundless on this topic: http://boundlessgeo.com/2013/01/chaining-rendering-transformations-in-geoserver/.

Comment: The question seems to be specific about CartoDB...